# Batch-convert images from colour to grayscale in python

Tags: python, batch-processing, data-conversion

So I have a batch of colour images and I'd want  to make them grayscale. The only problem is, sometimes the images are of shape `[batch_size, channels, height, width]` and sometimes they are `[batch_size, height, width, channels]`. I need a function that takes a batch of colour images (no matter which of the two shapes it has) and gives a batch of grayscale images of shape `[batch_size, height, width, channels]` (with channels being 1, of course).

So far I have this function:

```
from scipy import misc

def color_to_grayscale(image_batch, dim_order='NHWC'):

   grayscale_batch = np.array()

   if dim_order='NCHW':
    image_batches =  np.transpose(image_batch, [0, 2, 3, 1])
   else:
    image_batches = image_batch

   for idx in range(image_batches[0].shape):
    image = image_batches[idx, :, :, :]
    grayscale = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))

    for rownum in range(len(image)):
        for colnum in range(len(image[rownum])):
            grayscale[rownum][colnum] = np.average(image[rownum][colnum])

    grayscale = np.array(grayscale, dtype="float32")
    grayscale = grayscale.reshape((grayscale.shape[0], grayscale.shape[1], 1))

    grayscale_batch = np.stack(grayscale, grayscale_batch)

return grayscale_batch
```

I'm thinking of doing an np.vstack at the end of the for loop to reconstruct the batch, but it looks messy. Also I am not considering both cases above (dimensions) here.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Updated code to something I'm expecting to work (but still does not).

Comment: Are you sure about `for idx in range(image_batches[0].shape)`?

Comment: Nope, it gives me an error there.

Comment: I guess you meant `image_batches.shape[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any loops, stacking or anything, just use `numpy.mean()` over your channels axis

```
# axis=-1 is channels, keepdims is optional
greyscale_image_batch = numpy.mean(image_batch, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
image_batch.shape             # [batch_size, height, width, channels]
greyscale_image_batch.shape   # [batch_size, height, width, 1]
```

To bring your array in right shape you can use `transpose()`:

```
if image_batch.shape[1] == 3:
    image_batch = image_batch.transpose([0, 2, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Not sure I get the first part of your answer, with the numpy.mean. I also updated my function to something as complete as I could get it.